# I cannot find "upgrade current target for ipad" in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I followed "iPad Programming Guide" from Apple to try to upgrade one of my iPhone project for iPad. But I cannot find the menu item of "upgrade current target for ipad" even after I selected one of the Targets.

What is the reason? My SDK version is 3.1.3.

Thank you.

The screenshot is [here](http://i46.tinypic.com/14watlc.jpg)

Comment: The minimums are SDK 3.2 and MacOS 10.6 for iPad.

Comment: Thank you drawnonward. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPad development requires iPhone SDK 3.2. You can download it for free from the [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action).